# How do I recursively ftp only certain file types from a linux server using the command line?

Tags: file, recursion, ftp, types

I want to download only .htm or .html files from my server.  I'm trying to use ncftpget and even wget but only with limited success.

with ncftpget I can download the whole tree structure no problem but can't seem to specify which files I want, it's either all or nothing.

If I specify the file type like this, it only looks in the top folder:

```
ncftpget -R -u myuser -p mypass ftp://ftp.myserver.com/public_html/*.htm ./local_folder
```

If I do this, it downloads the whole site and not just .htm files:

```
ncftpget -R -u myuser -p mypass ftp://ftp.myserver.com/public_html/ ./local_folder *.htm
```

Can I use ncftp to do this, or is there another tool I should be using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with wget

```
wget -r -np -A "*.htm*" ftp://site/dir
```

or:

```
wget -m -np -A "*.htm*" ftp://user:pass@host/dir
```

However, as per [Types of Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Types-of-Files.html):

> Note that these two options do not affect the downloading of HTML files (as determined by a `.htm` or `.html` filename prefix). This behavior may not be desirable for all users, and may be changed for future versions of Wget.

Comment: You should escape `*.htm*` to pass it to wget with `'*.htm*'` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Does ncftpget understand dir globs?

Try

```
ncftpget -R -u myuser -p mypass ftp://ftp.myserver.com/public_html/**/*.htm ./local_folder
```

** means any number of directories.

Answer (score 0):

The `wget` command understands standing unix file globbing syntax.

```
wget -r -np --ftp-user=username --ftp-password=password "ftp://example.com/path/to/dir/*.htm"
```

Conversely, you can use the `-A` option, which accepts a comma-separated list of file name suffixes or patterns to accept.

```
wget -A '*.htm'
```

The `-R` option is the opposite of `-A`, so you can use it to specify patterns NOT to fetch.

Caveat: Make sure to quote patterns! Otherwise, your shell *may* expand the glob itself, leading to unexpected results.

Also! See the ["Using wget to recursively download whole FTP directories"](https://serverfault.com/questions/25199/using-wget-to-recursively-download-whole-ftp-directories) question on Server Fault.